Mat-Expansion Panel stay closed on drag
I'm working with a mat-expansion-panel that makes up the main body of a cdk popup. The popup can be dragged around the screen.
Because of this, I want a regular click to open the panel, and any type of click + hold to not open the panel (as a user will do this to move the panel around the page instead). The default behavior of the panel is to open in response to any type of left click, and I'm struggling to find a way to prevent this on a click + hold.

I have tried using the expanded and disabled inputs and toggling to false (or true, then false immediately after) when the panel is expanded on a click + hold. Both have not worked for different reasons.


please share the minimal reproducible code, if possible a stackblitz where the issue happens, steps to replicate and expected output.
